# Weighting of an already calculated average

Tags: r, mean

I have this kind of data:

```
category <- c("A", "B", "C", "B", "B", "B", "C")
mean <- c(5,4,5,4,3,1,5)
counts <- c(5, 200, 300, 150, 400, 200,250)

df <- data.frame(category, mean, counts)
```

`category` is some kind of factor, `mean` is an already calculated average. `mean` was calculated through different shapes of a scale (1-5) and the number of `counts`. I just have the calculated `mean`s and not the single values it was calculated from.

The goal is to aggregate the different `mean`s over the different `category`s. Like this:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% group_by(category) %>% 
  summarise(weighted.mean(mean, counts))

A   5.000000        
B   2.947368        
C   5.000000
```

The problem is that it is more valuable (in my case) to get an average from higher `counts` like `C` (550) then from lower counts like `A` (5). Any Idea how to take this into account?

My solution would be this one. But I don´t know if it´s valid:

```
df %>% mutate(y = mean * counts) %>%
  mutate(category = as.factor(category)) %>%
  group_by(category) %>%
    summarise(X = sum(y)) %>%
  arrange(desc(X))


B   2800            
C   2750            
A   25
```

Comment: I'm confused by your question. You're already taking a weighted average for each variable (A, B and C). And the counts won't make a difference for A and C like you're suggesting. A only has one mean of 5, and C only has two means of 5, so their means will always be 5. Placing more/less weight (or none) on the counts will not change this: the mean of 5 counts of "5" is 5, much like the mean of 550 counts of "5" is 5.

Comment: You already have the weighted average. If you would like to use different weights (e.g., not a linear function of `counts` but something more extreme) you can easily do it, the only question is, which weights would be justifiable.

Comment: @ MBorg/lebatsnok: The numbers are a scale. 5 is the highest possible value. I want to take the fact into account that it is much more difficult to get this value 550 times then 5 times. But I don´t know how to achieve this in a proper way.